# JS\JQuery - How do i get rid of prompts and make the programm wait for user's input and then react to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry it's s bit long, but i really dont understand how to ask my questions shorter.
I'm trying to made a simple javascript adventure game.
All the basic functions for example: newGame(), selectChar(), fight(), etc... are ready and working well.
User interface is working and user can interact with it by typing messages. into the input line and by pressing enter(or a button) his message will apper in the dialog box.
I have a short(test) story line.

But i cant get how to bind everything work together as i want.

The first problem is:
I dont understand how user could use the html input line to interact with in-game switches and if\else statements. (instead of prompt()) - for example:
 User have to input one of those numbers: 1, 2 to move to the next switch or if\else.
I tried every thing i could find on web, but nothing helps(or i just dont understand the really problem).

I even tried to use a prompt untill i will find a way to solve the first problem, but the second problem is:
All the prompts are appearing one after one, and only when all the prompts are "done", i get the results of all those prompts on the dialog box.(think that i have some problem with DOM - maybe (document)ready should be in another place or some thing in this key.).

So the main question is: How do i get rid of prompts and make the programm wait for user's input and then react to it as it have to. 
It seams to be simple but this is my very first coding project and i already broke my head and dont know how to move next.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

// This is the user's variable that shows which main character was choosed by user(user value will be defined via selectChar() function):
var user;
var friend;

// Creating a Person constructor - with this constuctor we can made a friend or an enemy:
function Person(name, age, type, hp, power, resist, str, fellowship, credits, aClass ){
/*default*/this.alive = true;
/*1*/      this.name = name;
/*2*/      this.age = age;
/*3*/      this.type = type;
/*4*/      this.hp = hp;
/*5*/      this.power = power;
/*6*/      this.resist = resist;
/**/     //this.socSkl = socSkl; - instead of "socSkl", added attribute "power".
/*7*/      this.str = str;
/*8*/      this.fellowship = fellowship;
/*9*/      this.credits = credits;
/*10*/     this.aClass = "Jedi";
if(this.hp >0){
    this.alive = true;
}else{
    this.alive = false;
}
};

// Creating two objects from a Person class:
var phantomorph = new Person("Phantomorph",26,"Cyborg",5,3,8,2,6,10, "Jedi");

var disogr = new Person ("Disogr",30,"dark Elf",5,6,6,1,6,10, "Jedi");


// This is a showText function, it will show needed text on the story board:
var showText = function(text){
  $("#storyBoard").append(text+"<br />");
/*When a total amount of text inside story board will be more then the size of a story board window, this script will automaticly scroll down
    every time when appending additional text. */
var element = document.getElementById("storyBoard");
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
};

// This is a button click function. When user clicks the Enter button with the left mouse, all the text from the input appends to the story board.
$("#btn").click(function(){
        var btnClick = $("input[name=myInput]").val();
        $("#storyBoard").append(btnClick+"<br>");
        $("input[name=myInput]").val("");
        var element = document.getElementById("storyBoard");
element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
        });

// It is an additional function for button click function, that allows user to press enter button on a keyboard to call the click button function.
 $("#userInput").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#btn").click();
    }
});

// Creating an AUTOMATIC fight 1vs1 function, that takes two parameters:
var fight = function(char, enemy){
    if (char === enemy){
        showText("You just committed suicide");
        return char.alive = false;
    }else{
    while(char.alive && enemy.alive){
    var charStrike = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 * char.str);
       showText(char.name + " strikes " + enemy.name + " for " + charStrike + " dmg");
            if(charStrike < enemy.hp){
                enemy.hp -= charStrike;
                showText(enemy.name+"'s Hp now is: " + enemy.hp);
     var enemyStrike = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 * enemy.str);
        showText(enemy.name + " strikes " + char.name + " for " + enemyStrike + " dmg");
           } else if (charStrike >= enemy.hp) {
                enemy.alive = false
                 showText(enemy.name  + " dies.");
                 break;
           };

            if(enemyStrike < char.hp){
                char.hp -= enemyStrike;
                showText(char.name+"'s Hp now is: " + char.hp);

            }else if (enemyStrike >= char.hp) {
                char.alive = false;
                showText(char.name + " dies.");
                break;
};
};
};
};

var stats = function(char){
if (char.alive){
    showText("Name: " + char.name +
        ",<br> Age: " + char.age +
         ",<br> HP: " + char.hp +
          ",<br> Strength: " + char.str +
          ",<br> Power: " + char.power +
     ",<br> Mental resistance: " + char.resist +
     ",<br> Credits " + char.credits);

        if(char.fellowship >= 5){
            showText(char.name+"'s fellowship is " + char.fellowship);
        }else if (char.fellowship > 2 ){
            showText(char.name+"'s fellowship is " + char.fellowship);
            showText(char.name+"'s fellowship to you is getting low. Fix it before it breaks.");

        }else{

            showText(char.name+"'s fellowship is " + char.fellowship);
            alert(char.name+"'s fellowship to you is to low. If it will fall more, you never be friends agains.");
        };
    }else{
    showText(char.name + " is dead. Game over. ");
}
};

//A first in-game function, needs to select the character that user want to be:
var selectChar = function(){
    showText("Choose who you are, you have to choose between two options: 'Phantomorph' or 'Disogr', \
they both are novice jedi knights but the first one is a cyborg and the second one is a dark Elf. \
Please, do not ask, how the hell dark Elf and cyborg have became jedies... it's so secret information that even they know nothing about it. \
Make a choice of 'who you are' by typing the name of the hero you want to be.");
var select = prompt("Choose who you are, you have to choose between two options: 'Phantomorph' and 'Disogr'").toLowerCase();
    switch(select){
        case "phantomorph": showText("You choosed Phantomorph."); user = phantomorph; friend = disogr;
        break;
        case "disogr": showText("You choosed Disogr."); user = disogr; friend = phantomorph;
        break;
        default: alert("You need to make a right choose."); selectChar();
        break;
        };

    };
//A function that shows basic game information, can be called by user at any time.
var info = function(){
showText("The basic information & rules you have to know before you get started, are:")
    showText("1)Your powers is too great to let you just use them all. \
It may break the system and collapse the whole universe, so our headship had created a special helm to help you\
controlling your power and they gave this thing a name: 'the Machine'.<br>");
    showText("2) Soon you will start to recieve very important missions. To success you only have:<br/>\
    1) To stay alive<br>\
    2) To keep your ally stay alive<br>\
    3) To keep your 'fellowship' value as high as it is possible<br>\
    4) To keep ally 'fellowship' value as high as it is possible<br>");
};

var mission1 = function(){
    showText("Welcome to the virtual pseudo-reality.\
     Are you ready to start your journey?")
    var story = prompt("Welcome to the virtual pseudo-reality. Are you ready to start your journey?").toLowerCase();

        switch (story){
            case "yes": showText("Yes"); showText("Welcome aboard!");selectChar();
            showText("You met your old friend that for some reason starting to fight against you!")
            fight(friend, user); break;
            case "no": showText("Your choise is no.");break
            default: showText("default"); break;

        }


        };

mission1();
stats(user);
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid #232C01;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 5em;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    background-color: #070900;
    background-image: url(images/Star-Wars-7-Poster-Banner.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 150%;
    height: 75em;
    width:135em;
}

/*#logo{
 height: 10em;

}
*/
#storyBoard{
    border: .1em solid #f0ff00  ;
    background-color: #000000 ;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    height: 80%;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: #f3fd4e;
    opacity: .95;
    overflow:auto;




}


#userInput{
    border: .1em solid #adae32;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: 4%;
    font-size: 3em;
    width: 85%;
    color:  white;


}

#btn{
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: #0E1200;
    width: 3em;
    color: #feff6c;
    margin-left: -.3%;


}
/*
@import "compass/css3";

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share+Tech+Mono);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>MacroG0D - My first game</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src ='Js/basicFight1vs1Function.js' type="text/javascript"> </script>



<!-- <script src='vars.js' type="text/javascript"></script>-->
</head>

<body>

<!--<img id="logo" src="images/topLogo.png"> -->

<div id = "storyBoard"></div>
<div id="userInterface">
<input type="text" id ="userInput" placeholder="Type the command here" name="myInput"/>
<button id = "btn"> Enter </button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is too long. I know you are aware of that, but that doesn't help. StackOverflow is not the site where you can dump an entire program and people debug it for you. You *need* to limit yourself. Ask specific questions about specific parts of your program. Dissecting the problem into multiple independent bits will A) help you understand it better and B) get you answers instead of downvotes. Most likely you will find that many of the small questions have been asked and answered before, but you need to sit down and make small questions first.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the next code (the keyboard arrows or the button on the display will move the red square):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            demo for game
        </title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div#divBG { position:absolute;  top:50%; left:0%; width:100%; height:20px; border:solid 1px black; }
            div#divMove { position:absolute; top:0%; left:50%;}
            div#divSquare { position:absolute; top:0%; width:20px; background-color:red; height:20px; }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            'use strict';
            var m_moveDir = 0;
            var m_CurPos = 50;
            var m_MovableObj = null;

            function SetMove(move_dir) {
                m_moveDir = move_dir;
            }

            function Init() {
                m_MovableObj = document.getElementById('divMove');
                setInterval (DoMove,10);
                document.onkeydown = onkeydown;
                document.onkeyup = onkeyup;

            }

            function DoMove() {
                m_CurPos += m_moveDir;
                if (0 > m_CurPos) {
                    m_CurPos = 0;
                }
                if (100 < m_CurPos) {
                    m_CurPos = 100;
                }
                m_MovableObj.style.left = m_CurPos + "%";
            }

            function onkeydown(evt) {
                evt = evt || window.event;
                switch (evt.keyCode) {
                    case 37:
                        SetMove(-0.1);
                        break;
                    case 39:
                        SetMove(0.1);
                        break;
                }
            }           

            function onkeyup (evt) {
                evt = evt || window.event;
                switch (evt.keyCode) {
                    case 37:
                        SetMove(-0.0);
                        break;
                    case 39:
                        SetMove(-0.0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='Init();'>
        <div id='divBG'>
            <div id='divMove'>
                <div id='divSquare'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button onmousedown = 'SetMove(0.1);' onmouseup = 'SetMove(0.0)'>  ----> </button>
        <button onmousedown = 'SetMove(-0.1);' onmouseup = 'SetMove(0.0)'>  <---- </button>
    </body>
</html>
```